# Shape placement and shape counter

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I've got a few questions about shapes in VBA Excel.

I've got Column A and Column B. They will be shown like this.

```
    A            B
1 | some text    1 to 5 shapes
2 | blabla       OOOO
```

I want to input the text and the shapes through a userform. So if a user selects '1', i want one shape to appear at the left of the cell in column B. If a user selects '3', I want 3 shapes to appear next to each other in column B.

Also, if someone firstly chooses to have 3 shapes, and wants to change it to 4 shapes later, I have to put the fourth shape in the right place.

All of this must still work if I change the widths of the columns.

I really googled a lot, but I can't seem to find a right solution.

Comment: Which cell in column **A** should be used to locate the *Shapes ??*

Comment: I'm searching for something like `coords = shape1.position` or something. The shapes aren't to be located from column A. Something like `range("b1").countShapes`, and something like `shape1.position = coords`

Comment: A shape has a `Top` and `Left` properties. It also has a `TopLeftCell` property which is assigned a Range object. You can use these properties to position the shapes to a cell and relative to other shapes (by adding the `.Width` to the `.Left` of the previous shape, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit works for me, but of course you'll have to modify to use your own shapes and purpose.

```
Sub DrawShapesInPlace(shapeCell As Range, numShapes As Integer, Optional gap As Double = 3#)
    Dim cellW As Double
    Dim cellH As Double
    Dim shapeW As Double
    Dim shapeUL As Double
    Dim shapeTop As Double
    Dim shapeH As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim newShape As Shape

    If numShapes < 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    cellW = shapeCell.Width
    cellH = shapeCell.Height
    shapeW = (cellW / numShapes) - gap
    shapeUL = shapeCell.Left
    shapeTop = shapeCell.Top
    shapeH = cellH

    For i = 1 To numShapes
        Set newShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
                                                   shapeUL, _
                                                   shapeTop, _
                                                   shapeW, _
                                                   shapeH)
        newShape.Line.Weight = 1
        shapeUL = shapeUL + gap + shapeW
    Next i
End Sub

Sub DrawShapes()
    Call DrawShapesInPlace(ActiveSheet.Range("D9"), 3)
End Sub
```